# 'Undefined' JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

This is my first time using JSON. I have an external json file and I am using the json file in my html file to create divs with every json data read. I can get the correct output for all of the values, except for one which is the 'descript' value. I have tried printing it to the cosole log but all I'm getting for that particular value is 'undefined' but the other values are alright. Any idea on why this happened?

JSON file:

```
[{"title":"3G","filePath":"https://example.com","descript":"hello world"}, {"title":"4G", "filePath":"https://example.com", "descript": "test"} ]
```

HTML file:

```
 $.ajax({
      url : "testJSON.json",
      type : "get", // whichever you like
      contentType:"json",
      success : function(list)
        {           
          var divCol  = "<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>";
          var divWell = "<div class='well'>";
          var divClose= "</div>";

          list.forEach(function(obj, index) {

            var title     = "<h5>"      + obj.title    + "</h5>";
            var desc      = "<p>"       + obj.descript + "</p>";
            var linkStart = "<a class='btn btn-default' style='float:left' href='" + obj.filePath + "' target='_blank'>";
            var linkEnd   = "CSV</a>";
            var div = divCol    +
            divWell     +
            title       +
            desc        +
            linkStart       +
           // image       +
            linkEnd +
            divClose +
            divClose;


              console.log(list)
           $("#imdaFiles").append(div); // insert the div you've just created

           })
        }
    });
```

Comment: there is an error in the JSON file in "descript:" "test" as double quotes are after the colon. It should be  "descript": "test"

Comment: @DavisMolinari sorry, that was not part of the original code. The problem still persists

Comment: @nurul98 I m not sure, i  think its JSON string .Try with `list=JSON.parse(list)` on  success function 1st line

Comment: @prasad nope that did not work

Answer (score 3):

Just a short notice that might solve the issue.. you misplaced a double quote on the right side of the last `descript` key in your JSON.

Comment: that typo error is not part of the original code so the problem still persists